# Windows tool like AutoText in Word or iOS5's shortcuts?

Tags: automation, hotkeys

In Word you can define a marked section of text as an autotext by pressing Alt+F3. Give it a name and from then on, you can type the name of the autotext (that is short) and press F3 to have it replaced with the originally marked section.

iOS has this feature from version 5 on: Define a keyword (say "gm") and the text (say "Good morning,") and from then on, you can type "gm" to have "Good morning," for you.

Is there a really simple tool for Windows (XP, 7) that does this? It needs to be very simple: Explaining it to an average user should not take longer than a minute...
I am not looking for something that pastes some text hardwired to a keystroke (say Ctrl+Shift+G -> "Good morning,"). The tool should use the last typd characters as a text selector.

I am aware of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), but that is way too complicated for an average user.

**Edit:** [PhraseExpress's autotext](http://www.phraseexpress.com/docs8/09/manual.htm#autotext)-feature is what I need, but we tested that tool and it is too bloated. All the menus scare our users away from using it.

Answer (score 1):

Jitbit Autotext, PhraseExpress and TeDa Pro(free).

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. TeDa Pro is old, but actually free (as in beer). PhraseExpander is free (as in beer) for personal use and  inherits some of PhraseExpress' clunkyness. Jitbit Autotext seems to be exactly what I looked for and costs money.

Comment: AutoText is also free now

Answer (score 0):

Somehow an earlier answer disappeared: [InstantType](http://www.text-inserter.com/) is the skinny, athletic brother of PhraseExpress. Not fancy - just gets the job done without any fuss. Colleagues love it.

It is free (as in beer) but seems to randomly die after several days of running on Win7 64bit. On XP it seems to work fine so far.